# Java if input ends in a certain pattern

Tags: java

My program takes an input (word) checks if the word ends with qu if its true then it changes the qu to ed

```
String lastLetters = word.substring (word.length () - 2);

    if (2Letters.equalsIgnoreCase ("qu")) {
        return true;
    }

    if (endsWithQU == true) {
        output = word.replaceAll ("ew", "ed");
    }else


    return false;
```

i have this but it doesnt really work im not sure how to properly code this

Comment: hard to decipher what your method is, it looks like you chopped a bit out and the formatting was garbled up

Answer (score 1):

From what I could gather from your code, I believe this is what you're asking:

```
public static boolean ifEndsInQu(String word){
    if(word.substring(word.length()-2).equalsIgnoreCase("qu"))
         return true;

    return false;
}
```

or

```
public static String ifEndsInQu(String word){
    if(word.substring(word.length()-2).equalsIgnoreCase("qu"))
         return word.subString(0, word.length()-2) + "ed";

    return word;
}
```